# why git ls-tree works weirdly in subdirectories?

Tags: git

when I'm running git ls tree for retrieving a folder from subdirectory(directory is where the git repo is located) instead of viewing the expected result, its just empty...so what's the reason for this behaviour?

d:lome=directiry

d:lome/hello=subdirectory

```
d:lome/hello>
git ls-tree head
100644 blob 6d97d903effbe6a20d6e4023b86986c75f39a1ae    11111.txt
040000 tree 881e54f5976f3e8fc407568ca8361fb8c469a490    hellonew3

d:lome/hello>
git ls-tree 881e5
```

expected result:

```
040000 tree f8c7edbbe07efc554c620cc6eae928b17fb3941a    hellonew4
100644 blob fd8f694894c93d8b756a54ed85fb5556d77799da    lome.txt
```

result:
empty

by the way, when I want to access specific folder from directory, it just works fine...

```
d:lome>
git ls-tree 881e5
```

expected result:

```
040000 tree f8c7edbbe07efc554c620cc6eae928b17fb3941a    hellonew4
100644 blob fd8f694894c93d8b756a54ed85fb5556d77799da    lome.txt
```

result:

```
040000 tree f8c7edbbe07efc554c620cc6eae928b17fb3941a    hellonew4
100644 blob fd8f694894c93d8b756a54ed85fb5556d77799da    lome.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your command to

```
git ls-tree --full-tree 881e5
```

Otherwise, it looks for `881e5` starting where you are, and fails to find it.